# MonoTouch Dialog elements are not updating/repainting themselves

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have the following in a Section:

```
            _favElement = new StyledStringElement (string.Empty);
            _favElement.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

            if (_room.IsFavourite) {
                _favElement.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/thumbs_up.png");
                _favElement.Caption = "Unmark as Favourite";
            } else {
                _favElement.Image = null;
                _favElement.Caption = "Mark as Favourite";
            }

            _favElement.Tapped += favElement_Tapped;
```

Then when I press the element I want the following to happen:

```
        private void favElement_Tapped ()
        {
            if (_room.IsFavourite) {
                _favElement.Image = null;
                _favElement.Caption = "Mark as Favourite";
            } else {
                _favElement.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/thumbs_up.png");
                _favElement.Caption = "Unmark as Favourite";
            }   

            _room.IsFavourite = !_room.IsFavourite;
        }
```

However the image and text does not change in the actual element when the element is tapped. Is there a refresh method or something that must be called? I've also tried changing the Accessory on Tapped as well and nothing changes. The properties behind do reflect the correct values though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming that your code is in DialogViewController,add this

```
this.ReloadData();
```

but in your case I recommend you to use BooleanImageElement

Comment: If you end up using `BooleanImageElement` then either wait for a fix (or apply the patch to you copy of MT.D)  to: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3970#c2

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to reloading the `UITableView` is to reload the `Element` using code like this (copied from [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/blob/master/NUnitLite/TouchRunner/TestElement.cs#L44)):

```
if (GetContainerTableView () != null) {
    var root = GetImmediateRootElement ();
    root.Reload (this, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
}
```